# POST request on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

I have the following problem.
A web service is sending a JSON POST request to my app on Heroku and I want to parse it.

If I look into my Heroku logs, I see that there was a POST request but it got an error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches....)
```

But a GET request works fine, no error.

I'm pretty new to Rails so I don't know  what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All paths (URLs), with their associated HTTP verbs and with other associated constraints, must be declared in `config/routes.rb`.

```
# config/routes.rb (Rails 3)
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  get 'my-service' => 'service#index' # ServiceController#index
  post 'my-service' => 'service#update' # ServiceController#update

end
```

Once routes are defined, Rails will respond to the corresonding verb/path the way you specify - usually, loading the controller and running the action you specify.

```
# app/service_controller.rb
class ServiceController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # do reading/displaying stuff here
  end

  def update
    # do updating stuff here
  end

end
```